# Compile svgcleaner-gui on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qt

I would like to compile `svgcleaner-gui` on an ubuntu 16.04. So I cloned the git [repo](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui) and followed the instructions:

```
qmake
make
```

whereby `make` gives that error:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB
-DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux
g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr
/include/qt4/QtSvg -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:26:26: fatal error: QVersionNumber: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:395: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I have installed the qt-creator as described in the homepage (using the downloaded *.run file), but the error remains the same.

What am I missing here?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui/blob/master/README.md) it needs Qt version >= 5.6 but you appear to be building against Qt4.

Comment: Any Idea how I can update the version??

Comment: If you have Qt5 installed try running `qmake-qt5` rather than `qmake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QVersionNumber` was added in Qt 5.6. Make sure that you are compiling against the correct version of Qt.

According to the [svgcleaner-gui GitHub page](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui), the required version of Qt is 5.6 or higher.

You can download the open source version of Qt from [qt.io](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2)